# ClassNotFoundException in activity

Tags: android, android-activity

i make a android application,i maked a activity (company_about_us) and next time i delete it,but some times my application crash and on the error log make message about it.
Activity Log:
[image]

and also after kill application,show onstop popup about this application.

Sorry my English is not good

help me please

Comment: check whether you have called `company_about_us` anywhere in your project.

Comment: i never call this activity

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is some error in Eclipse because after restarting the computer it will work again. Sometimes Eclipse produces inexplicable errors which are only solved by restarting Eclipse or even the whole computer

Comment: yes,thats right but i have problem on my phone,i should restart my phone,it's not good

Comment: I can't understand what do you want to say!

Comment: when i close my application,after some minutes,show popup about onstop my application,when i turn on my phone it dosent show that popup.on emulator i kill adb.exe and work it.

Answer (score 0):

You may has registered this activity "**company_about_us**" in the **manifest xml** file, try to check it.

if so, remove the xml declaration.

Comment: thanks for your comment but i was remove it on  manifest xml file